# Difference between Promise and Success in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am bit confused between success call back in Ajax and Promise.

Let me try to explain my confusion with an example.

```
$http.get("https://someapi.com").success(function (){})
```

In the above code, success it our callback function which is going to be executed whenever the asynchronous operation completes .. right?

Now coming to Promise.

We create a promise to handle both the Success and Failure (Resolve and Reject)

Now my question, when we have call back provision in Ajax, why do we need promise?

Comment: How about looking at https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-promise-and-a-callback-in-Javascript ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using promises is just that they provide a powerful, common interface for async tasks.

The main benefit of a common interface (any common interface) is that you can write and use higher-level functions that operate on promises.  As just one example, many promise libraries provide a function, often called `all`, that takes a set of promises, and returns a new promise that encapsulates all of them.  Then you can write things like:

```
promise.all(promise1, promise2).then(function (value1, value2) {
    // blah blah
});
```

instead of this pyramid code

```
promise1.then(function (value1) {
    promise2.then(function (value2) {
        // blah blah
    });
});
```

And of course you can only use functions like `all` if you're using async tasks with some known, common interface.  It would be impossible if some had `.then` methods, some had `.success` methods, and so on.

The `promise` interface has other useful properties, for instance the `.then` method on a promise returns a promise - and if the callback you pass it returns a promise, the `.then` method returns a promise that actually awaits the promise returned by the callback.  In other words:

```
// p1 is a promise that resolves to 1, when somePromise resolves
var p1 = somePromise.then(function (value) {
    return 1;
});

// p2 is a promise that resolves to what someOtherPromise resolves to,
// not to someOtherPromise itself
var p2 = somePromise.then(function (value) {
    return someOtherPromise;
});
```

Which makes it nice and easy to make a series of HTTP calls, one after another.

There are some drawbacks to using promises too...  By convention, they wrap your callback in a try/catch block, so if you throw an exception it will be caught, sometimes invisibly.

```
somePromise.then(function (value) {
    throw 'error';
}).catch(function (error) {
    // without this catch block, the error may be eaten invisibly
    console.error(error);
});
```

To sum up, a promise is just a widely-used interface for managing asynchronous tasks.  Use it if you want, don't if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

[Promises](http://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/) allow to be able to use the result of the callback and/or chain several calls together to manipulate the result.  With the introduction of async/await, it can make asynchronous code a lot simpler.

With callbacks it can be done, but with lots of nesting and potential confusion.

With Callbacks:

```
 $http.get('https://something.com/rest/returns5').success(function(result) {
    if (result) {
       var finalValue = result - 4;
       // to use the result you'll need another nested callback here
       callback(finalValue); // what scope did this come from? where did this come from? :-)
    }
 });
```

With Promises:

```
 $http.get('https://something.com/rest/returns5')
      .then(function(result) {
          return result - 4;
      })
      .then(function(result) {
          // use the result from the previous chained promise call (result - 4) 
      });
```